# Why doesn't repeated PatternSequence work with explicit pattern names?

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Why would this work:

```
Clear[f]
f[a : PatternSequence[b_, c_]] := {a};
f[1, 2]
(* {1, 2} *)
```

and this also works:

```
Clear[f]
f[a : PatternSequence[_, _] ..] := {a};
f[1, 2, 3, 4]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

but this does not work?

```
Clear[f]
f[a : PatternSequence[b_, c_] ..] := {a};
f[1, 2, 3, 4]
(* f[1, 2, 3, 4] *)
```

---

**Edit**: Now that @RunnyKine's answer and @kguler's comment have perfectly answered my original question, I have another related question: is there a pattern-based way that I could extract the first element of the repeated pattern sequence without doing this?

```
Clear[fNew]
fNew[a : PatternSequence[_, _] ..] := Partition[{a}, 2][[All, 1]]
fNew[1, 2, 3, 4]
(* {1, 3} *)
```

Comment: The fact that `f[3, 4, 3, 4]` and `f[1, 2, 1, 2]` works suggests why `f[1,2,3,4]` does not work,  no?

Comment: ahh. gotcha! Thanks so much to you both.

Comment: The purpose of argument patterns on the lefthand side of a `Set` or `SetDelayed` is to allow the evaluator to determine which, if any, down-values can be used for further evaluation of the expression. It is **not** intended to be and can not be use as a kind macro preprocessor for modifying the argument sequence. So the answer to latest question is: no.

Comment: For the update to your question, `fNew[a : (PatternSequence[_, _] ..)] := {a}[[1 ;; ;; 2]]` will do it efficiently. `fNew[a : (PatternSequence[_, _] ..)] := Downsample[{a}, 2]` will do the same.

Comment: @rasher, I think OP's looking for a pattern-based way on the RHS. See OP's comment below my answer.

Comment: Thanks @rasher! Your method seems to be the best one yet to do what I want; the reason why I decided to assign the names to the pattern sequence in the first place is to someone use that name to manipulate them in the function definition. Using a pattern (without naming it) as a parameter and then having to seek for what that pattern is again in the RHS seem a little backward to me. I think m_goldberg's comment kinda addresses that but I don't quite feel advanced enough to know precisely what he/she was talking about (researching for what down-values were hurt my head).

Comment: @seismatica In my opinion your addendum would be better as a separate follow-up question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `PatternSequence` rather the problem is with how you use `Repeated` (`..`). Take for example the following function definition:

```
f[x : {{_, _} ..}] := Norm[N[x]]
```

Now if we feed it the following input:

```
f[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}]
```

The function works as expected and yields:

```
4.07914333
```

Now let's redefine the function as follows (we use `g` instead)

```
g[x : {{a_, b_} ..}] := Norm[N[x]]
```

Now notice it looks just like `f` above but we've introduced the pattern objects `a_` and `b_`

We feed it the same input as above:

```
g[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}]
```

And we get:

```
g[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}]
```

Well, strange, nothing happens. No match. Now let's try a different input, one where the first pair is repeated:

```
g[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

Now we get:

```
2.44948974
```

A different input with the first pair repeated:

```
g[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}]
```

Yields

```
3.87298335
```

So, you see that `Repeated` works in mysterious ways, well, not really. The point here is that, with no explicit pattern, you get a structural match (for lack of a better term) but with explicit pattern names you have to repeat terms just like the pattern describes.
So for your last example, if you do:

```
f[1, 2, 1, 2]
```

You get:

```
{1, 2, 1, 2}
```

and

```
f[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Gives:

```
{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}
```

As expected.

Comment: Thanks @RunnyKine! This explains it perfectly, though if you have any insight on the related question I added in my question edit I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @seismatica, are you talking about replacing both `Partition`ing the `List` and collecting the first term of each `List` with a pattern-based approach or just the first term part?

Comment: I wanted to collect the first term of each `PatternSequence` without starting from `a` if that's at all possible.

Comment: @seismatica. I can't see a way to do that. Maybe someone else could help.